# How to get a reference to the TextView that displays an app's name

Tags: android

I want to get a reference to the TextView that displays name of the app. E.g. I have code like this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Jain_aartisActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

and I want to get reference to the TextView that displays the `app_name` string.

Comment: And why you want to get that view?

Comment: I need to change the typeface so that the TextView can display hindi characters. My app_name is जैन आरती संग्रेह. This does not get displayed properly by default.

Comment: what version of android platform you using? Are you using emulator or device? Also are you facing this issue only for title or somewhere else too?

Comment: 2.1. I had to change the typeface everywhere to support hindi characters. I am testing on emulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the view and replace it with your own then try the below code.

```
activity.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.your_layout);
```

`activity` could be `this` if called from within the activity.

Edit: It worked but you have to have a unicode font on your device/emulator. Well I cant say for all devices but mine have the font pre-installed and below are the snapshots.

[image: unicode image]

my `strings.xml` file contain

```
 <string name="app_name">जैन आरती संग्रेह</string>
```

Edit 2:

If you have the typeface with you then just create a small layout that looks like title bar and use the above mentioned code to replace the default title bar with yours.